# How to pass Input Stream between Activities via Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, inputstream

I have an `InputStream` object

```
InputStream _fileInput;
```

I want to send it to another activity, let's say:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass it via `Intent`, and neither as an `Extra` (since it's not `Parcelable`) you could create a public `getter` method in your MainActivity and invoke it in your `ChildActivity`..

sample code:

```
class MainActivity {

    private static InputStream mInputStream;

    @Override
    protected onCreate(...) {

        mInputStream = new InputStream(.....);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public static getInStream() {
        return mInputStream;
    }
}


class ChildActivity {

    @Override
    protected onCreate(...) {
        InputStream theInputStream = MainActivity.getInStream();
    }

}
```

Imho that's not the best solution but it's still something, thought I'd never pass something like an InputStream between activities..

If I can ask, why would you need this?

---

*Solution 2* - Using an Helper class

You could use a *Singleton* `Helper` class to make it easy to keep track of objects you need.

Class Helper will be:

```
class Helper {

    private static Helper mHelper;
    private InputStream mInputStream;

    private Helper(){

    }


    public static Helper getInstance() {
        if (mHelper != null)
            return mHelper;

        return new Helper();
    }


    public void setInputStreamer(InputStream is){
        mInputStream = is
    }

    public InputStream getInputStreamer(){
        return mInputStream
    }
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity` call:

```
is = new InputStream(...);
Helper.getInstance().setInputStreamer(is);

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And in your `ChildActivity` call:

```
InputStream theInputStream = Helper.getInstance().getInputStreamer();
```

Comment: Main activity is reading an excel file (input stream) and ChildActivity reading Sheet one by one and calling functions to plot the data. Every module is working fine separately but I am stuck here

Comment: I suggest you to keep this logic outside of Activities, Activity should be used **only** to handle user interactions. Everything that is not user interaction should be delegated to other components. I'd make write a Class that takes a file, reads it and interact with another class to read the sheets. Than you define proper methods to create interactions between you Activity and your "ExcelReader" class

Comment: Hello, as your suggestion I used above technique i.e. making it a static variable. It returns the variable in other class but when I used it says null value reference.

Comment: I'm glad it did! Remember to accept the answer, then! Have a nice day!

Comment: There is a mark on the right of the answer just below the votes

Comment: For more info about accepting and voting answers read this q/a on meta stackexchange http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/276801